# vba and postgresql connection

Tags: postgresql, excel, vba

I have a problem with connection from VisualBasic (Excel) to postgresql. 
I define my connection like that:

```
Set ObjMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
ObjMyConn.ConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode};Server=ip;Port=port;Database=db_name;Uid=user;Pwd=pass;"
ObjMyConn.Open
```

When I want to load 443532 rows into Excel with

```
Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = ObjMyConn
objMyCmd.CommandText = "select * from table"
objMyCmd.CommandType = adCmdText
objMyCmd.Execute
```

It keeps showing me run-time error *Out of memory error while reading tuples*.

I have already upgraded my ODBC driver to the latest version. I read [here](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Postgresql-Bindings-A-t1975599.html&p=2169606) that I have to set *Use declare/catch* to *true* somewhere (odbc driver I guess).

Is it possible to set it in VB code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can just add the `UseDeclareFetch=1`option to the connection string like this:

```
"Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode};Server=ip;Port=port;Database=db_name;Uid=user;Pwd=pass;UseDeclareFetch=1"
```

But, if that doesn't work, there's another method - if you have set up a ODBC system data source with the *ODBC Database Connection Administrator* you can modify the registry key directly (provided you have the sufficient permissions).

The key you want to change is located under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\PostgreSQL35W`if you're using a System DSN and the following vba code will enable `Use Declare/Fetch`:

```
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER     = &H80000001
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE    = &H80000002

strComputer = "."

Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &_
strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\PostgreSQL35W"
strValueName = "UseDeclareFetch"
strStringValues = "1"

oReg.SetStringValue   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,strStringValues
```

Comment: Right, so easy... first solution seems to be working fine. Thanks!